# Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Shell (Minimum) error in installation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When I'm installing Microsoft Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop I keep getting this error:

**Here is the screenshot:**

[image]

.

**Here is the log file:** http://pastebin.com/z95nT0st

I use MagicIso to extract the iso vs2013.4_dskexp_ENU. I tried to mount it into virtual disk too.

I fully reformatted my laptop so theres no old version of VS here.

Comment: Have a look in the log file (there is a  link on the error dialog)

Comment: @stuartd i already edited the thread and put the log there

Comment: @LorenceHernandez did all the files get extracted correctly? may be you have a bad ISO image. Try redownloading the image

Comment: @Amitd sorry for replying late, the size of iso is 6.8gb but it is supposed to be 6.51gb only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out now why I get that problem.

When I reformatted my laptop, I downloaded recovery software to recover the files I need (visual studio installer and others), and then when i install it, it didnt get installed successfully. So I deleted the file, but I think it already installed some other components of visual studio uncompletely before it fails to installed the vs.

Finally, I downloaded VS shell, and installed it in MVS folder but it fails to install half of it, so when I try again to install the VS, I got different error, it says the VS shell cannot be opened, (so this means I'm right) I get the error because its trying to open the "uncompletely" and continue to install it, but it cannot open it because its "uncomplete".

So now when I type this command **G:\wdexpress_full.exe/uninstall/force** in cmd, it deletes all the remnants of VS and then it fix my problem.

Comment: I have the same condition, also has problem with VS Shell, and install `Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Shell` solve that error, I met another error is when uninstalling `microsoft visual studio 2010 tools for office runtime`, and I manually uninstall twice from the control panel and solve it. finally same as this anwer I use cmd /uninstall /force success to uninstall, thanks.

Comment: @yuyangJian nice :) if you think its another way to solve it then feel free to edit that answer and add that :)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have downloaded a bad image. Download it again.

As an aside why not use the VS2013 [Community Version](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx)?